# Is there a way to apply pinch zoom for texts in jquery or angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pinchzoom

I am developing an hybrid android app. I need to apply pinch zoom for a particular content section. The text size should be increased on pinch zoom. I tried many methods but all of them are suggesting with image zoom instead of text zoom. Can any one help me please.

Answer (score 0):

That's not trivial. You can detect the pinch zoom state with [jQuery.documentSize](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.documentsize) (which I have written). The plugin is plain JS, and despite the name, you can use it [without jQuery](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.documentsize#dependencies-and-setup), too.

But that's only half the solution. You need to listen to a "pinch zoom" event which unfortunately doesn't exist – at least on the web. And the `"resize"` event doesn't work for it. According to Peter Paul Koch ("The Mobile Web Handbook"),

> ... most browsers fire the `resize` event when the layout viewport is resized, but not when the visual viewport is resized (that is, the user zooms). This rule  is not absolute, and to make things more complicated the several methods of resizing the layout or visual viewport may not all fire a `resize` event.

So unless you have access to an event in the Android app context which doesn't exist on the web, the only option seems to be polling, ie checking [`$.pinchZoomFactor()`](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.documentsize#zoom-level) in regular intervals.